# Texture coordinates passed to fragment shader are all 0

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I have written my own Vertex and Fragment shader for a little openGL 2.0 application I am working on.
Everything seems to work great except for one thing, the texture coordinate for every vertex seems to be (0, 0).

When I dont use my own shaders, that is, **when I use the default shader of openGL, then everything is drawn** ***fine***.

When I activate my own shader the shape is still okay, the vertex positions are correct. But the texture coordinates all become (0, 0).

Here is the code for the vertex shader:

```
in vec2 position;
in vec2 texcoord;

out vec2 coord;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(position, 0, 1);
    coord = vec2(gl_TextureMatrix[0] * vec4(texcoord, 1, 1));
}
```

And this is the fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;

uniform float redFactor;
uniform float greenFactor;
uniform float blueFactor;

in vec2 coord;
void main(void) {
    vec4 color = texture2D(texture, coord);
    float grey = (color.r * redFactor + color.g * greenFactor + color.b * blueFactor);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(grey, grey, grey, color.a);
}
```

Again, it works fine ***without my own shader***. So the VBO's are set up correctly.

By the way, the texcoords are correctly passed from the vertex shader to the fragment shader.
For example, when I change the line

```
coord = vec2(gl_TextureMatrix[0] * vec4(texcoord, 1, 1));
```

in the vertex shader to this:

```
coord = vec2(0.5, 0.5);
```

I get the correct result.

Here is how my VBO's content looks like:
    [0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0]

Here is the IBO for the drawing:

```
[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0]
```

Here are the pointers:

```
VERTEX_ARRAY_POINTER(size = 2, stride = 16, offset = 0),   
TEXCOORD_ARRAY_POINTER(size = 2, stride = 16, offset = 8)
```

Edit: By the way, what is wrong with the line break in this editor?

Comment: Line breaks are done with two spaces, if that is what you mean.

Comment: Where are your `#version` directives?  `in`/`out` aren't valid in `110`.  Anything in the shader compilation/link logs?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you need to enable the client state for the texture coordinates, so be sure to call `glEnableVertexAttribArray​` for positions and texture coordinates

for more details: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object

But that is if you are using vertex arrays, and from you question it seems like you are.

And personally, I enable all arrays that I'm using just before calling `glDraw*()` and then disabling all but the positions array after the draw call.

In order to know the index to use for `glEnableVertexAttribArray` you can use `0` for your positions and `1` for your texcoords.

A more robust answer would be that after you have program compiled and linked your program, make it current with `glUseProgram()` and then

> GLuint positionIndex = 0;
>   GLuint texcoordIndex = 1;
>   glUseProgram(programId);
>   glBindAttribLocation(programId, positionIndex, "position");
>   glBindAttribLocation(programId, texcoordIndex, "texcoord");

Then before your `glDraw*()`

> glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionIndex);
>   glEnableVertexAttribArray(texcoordIndex);

This is still a rather hard coded way of handling this, if you want a more generic method please leave a comment.

Since it was requested here is a generic way of knowing how many vertex attributes your shaders are using

```
glUseProgram(programId);

int attribCount;
glGetProgramiv(programId, GL_ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES, &attribCount);

GLuint attribLoc[] = new GLuint[attribCount];

for (int attrib=0; attrib<attribCount; ++attrib) {
    char szName[32];
    int size;
    GLenum vecType;
    glGetActiveAttrib(programId, attrib, sizeof(szName), 0, &size, &vecType, szName);

    attribLoc[attrib] = glGetAttribLocation(programId, szName);
    glBindAttribLocation(programId, attribLoc[attrib], szName);        
}
```

then when you go to draw

```
for (int attrib=0; attrib<attribCount; ++attrib) {
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribLoc[attrib]);
}

glDraw*();

for (int attrib=0; attrib<attribCount; ++attrib) {
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(attribLoc[attrib]);
}
```

Comment: I'd be interested in a more generic method.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of enabling and disabling vertex array states just for draw calls. Vertex Array Objects were created to persistently store vertex array setup independent of vertex buffer. Realistically, you might use 2+ different VAOs for a single VBO, depending on which vertex attributes your material (shaders) require, and where they require them. Then you simply bind a VAO that arranges your VBO's data appropriately whenever you draw a batch. The same goes for texture setup, these days you should bind sampler objects when all you really want to do is modify the texture filter state.

Comment: From forums posts people given me the impression that VAO's are slow to use because of __how much__ state a VAO changes. While looking for information to back this claim up, I've found that VAO's are not predictably slow or fast, so using VAO's would be a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using straight up vertex array pointer, texcoord array pointer, etc... API calls, then you will need to use the corresponding array in your shader.

More precisely, instead of using `in vec2 texcoord` (which is for generic vertex attributes), you would use `gl_TexCoord [0]` whenever you wanted to access the texture coordinates for texture unit 0 in your shader.

The fundamental problem here is you are mixing deprecated API features (`glTexCoordPointer`) with new GLSL constructs (`in` and `out`). nVIDIA drivers will actually alias calls like `glTexCoordPointer (...)` to a specific vertex attribute slot, but this is non-standard behavior and you should generally NEVER mix and match the two.

The only array pointer that is guaranteed to be aliased to a specific attribute slot by the OpenGL spec. is the vertex pointer, which aliases to attrib slot 0.

In the end, you will want to switch to vertex attrib arrays because they are much more flexible and are actually supported by core OpenGL :)

Comment: I see. This makes alot of sense.  So if I wanted to keep to the old version (since I already have all my render code set up this way) I would need to remove the In/Out variables and use gl_Vertex and gl_TexCoord instead?

Comment: Correct, if you use the old glVertexPointer, glTexCoordPointer, etc...   calls to setup your vertex arrays, then you should use gl_Vertex, gl_TexCoord, etc. to access the vertex data in your shaders. If/when you transition to using vertex attrib arrays, you would then use in variables. BTW, the only reason your shader _sort_ of works right now is because glVertexPointer aliases itself to attrib slot 0 (in other words, the very first _in_ attribute in your shader). In variables are really reserved for vertex attribs or to take the output from a previous shader stage (e.g vs passing data to fs)

Comment: In any case, you should make a habit of affixing a #version directive to the top of your shaders to avoid future confusion. If you want to limit yourself to only features present in pure OpenGL 2.0, you might use #version 110 (though this is automatically assumed). Starting with #version 130 (OpenGL 3.0) 'in' / 'out' replaced the 'varying' and 'attribute' type qualifiers, and shader stages no longer had their own type qualifiers ('attribute' used to be for vs input, 'varying' was for vs output/fs input, etc..)